# save dynamically create textboxs to table in cakephp 2.6

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

i started this project with idea of develop it with normal php,mysql. after all database design is completed. i was advised with use cakephp.

this my problem: 
 i am having a enquiry table which contain basic detail and enquiry description (which is 2 dimensional data) .

schema: enquiry is (id int auto..,company_id,{here i want the description detail(may contain N descriptions for single enquiry)},created,modified)

in general it is not possible to create like that so i create an other table for description with idea to refer it

schema: description (id int auto..,enquiry_id int,description varchar(55),detail(255))

as i am think that (in normal php while designing db) to use getLastId() and insert it with every description (insert) query.

To get/update description dynamically.i think of creating textbox and textarea for each description.

AFTER FRAMEWORK
i understand hasMany relationship and worked with some examples/tutorials. but they instruct me to insert only single entry for saving and retrieve both table data.

Q1. Is it correct db structure for cakephp2.6 r i should change table structure of enquiry and description table? if so advice me correct schema

Q2.is there is any way to do this(like storing and retrieve of enquiry and description?

Q3.if there is any thing i am missing about feature in cakephp related to my problem?

Q4.should i do this entirely manually? if so, recommend me methods for search(retrievel of data in view), add, update, delete to do this on both tables.

Here is my table look like

[image]

and my view look like this

[image]

i am suing mysql,cakephp 2.6.2
sry for my english

thanks in advance.(if u want more details i will provide it,put some comments)

Comment: Just read the following article , http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: What is 2 dimensional data? Please give an example of 2 dimensional data in your enquiry description field.

Comment: sorry to confuse u AgRizzo data like table format, data will be 2d array that is reterive from dynamically create textboxes.simple example data in school time table for each class

Comment: Please show an example of this data because it sounds like your database may not be normalized. Using Cakephp may be difficult with non-normalized database schemas. Please edit your question and put sample data in the question that would be found in your enquiry table. _(Your questions ask if db structure is correct, and if you can retrieve the data. Show sample data to get an accurate answer)_

Comment: @AgRizzo now what should i do, i like to save all the entries in that description to description table

Comment: Cakephp will work with your database schema. Use the [bake utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) and have Cakephp automatically build the basic data manipulation functionality. (Bake will not give you a form that looks exactly like the form you shared.) Using all the php code that was just created, you can create the Enquiry form you want.